# Confusion of proof on nowhere dense sets

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

I am reading the book `Measure and Category' by Oxtoby. In the first chapter, they focus solely on the real line. I am confused by the following proof:
[image]

I understand that, since $ A_1, A_2 $ are nowhere dense, given an interval $ I $, both sets are not dense on $ I $.
Therefore, there are subintervals $ I_1 ,I_2 $ that lie on the complement of $ A_1, A_2$.

The proof then says `Hence $ I_2 \subset I -(A_1 \cup A_2) $. I am struggling to see how that follows from the previous sentence. Surely, $  I -(A_1 \cup A_2) $ need not contain $  I -A_1 $?

Comment: It looks like you might have missed that the proof says that $I_2$ is taken to lie in $I_1 \setminus A_2$ rather than $I \setminus A_2$.  This means that $I_2$ is chosen from a set excluding $A_1$ by excluding $A_2$ further, which allows you to draw the conclusion regarding the union

Comment: To complement this question, if the OP is familiar with Baire's theorem: the intersection of dense open sets in locally compact spaces is also dense, then the result in Oxtoby's holds even for countable unions of nowhere dense sets (first category sets): If $(B_n:n\in\mathbb{N})$ is a sequence nowhere dense sets, so is $(\overline{B_n}:n\in\mathbb{N})$. If $U$ is open and $U\subset\bigcup_n\overline{B_n}$, then $V=\bigcap_n\big(\overline{B_n}\big)\subset U^c$. Each $\big(\overline{B_n}\big)$ is open and dense, hence by Baire's theorem, $V$ is dense. Then, $U^c=\mathbb{R}$ and so $U=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x \in I_2$. Then $x \in I$ because $I_2 \subset I_1\subset I$. $x \notin A_2$ is clear. Also $x\in I_1$ so $x \notin A_1$. It follows that $x \notin A_1\cup A_2$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $I_1\subset I\setminus A_1$ and $I_2\subset I_1\setminus A_2$ you have that
$$ I_2\subset(I\setminus A_1)\setminus A_2=I\cap (A_1)^c\cap(A_2)^c=I\cap(A_1\cup A_2)^c=I\setminus(A_1\cup A_2)$$
by [deMorgan's laws](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/deMorgansLaws.html).

Answer (score 2):

To complement the answers here, I'd like to add an alternative proof to the statement in question following one of the comments. We do not require the full generality of Baire's theorem, but only the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is separable.  One equivalence to saying that a  $A$ is nowhere dense is that its closure has empty interior: $\operatorname{int}(\overline{A})=\emptyset$. Suppose $A$ and $B$ are nowhere dense and $U$ is any open set $U\subset \overline{A\cup B}=\overline{A}\cup\overline{B}$. Then
$\Big(\overline{A}\Big)^c \cap \Big(\overline{B}\Big)^c\subset U^c$. The sets $\Big(\overline{A}\Big)^c$ and $\Big(\overline{B}\Big)^c$ are both open and dense in $\mathbb{R}$. It follows that $\Big(\overline{A}\Big)^c \cap \Big(\overline{B}\Big)^c$ is open and dense in $\mathbb{R}$. Since $U^c$ is closed and contains a dense set, it follows that $U^c=\mathbb{R}$. Consequently $U=\emptyset$. This shows that $\overline{A\cup B}$ has empty interior, that is $A\cup B$ is also nowhere dense.